# Unable to click on list element from drop down

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium WebDriver, I'm trying to click on `Manual Testing` option from `Testing` menu from http://guru99.com/  `Manual Testing` option appears after hovering mouse on `Testing`. In order to achieve above, I did following -

```
testing = $driver.find_element(:xpath, "//li[@class='item118 parent']")
mt = $driver.find_element(:xpath, "//li[@class='item119']/a")

$driver.action.move_to(testing).move_to(mt).perform
mt.click
```

But, sometimes error for line #3 above code -

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::MoveTargetOutOfBoundsError: Offset within element ca
nnot be scrolled into view: (85, 21): http://guru99.com/software-testing.html
```

and sometimes error for line #4 in above code -

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently vis
ible and so may not be interacted with
```

Please help me to resolve this issue **without executing javascript**.

Here is HTML code -

```
<li class="item118 parent">
  <a class="item" href="/software-testing.html"> Testing </a>
   <span class="dropdown-spacer"></span>
 <div class="dropdown columns-1 " style="width:180px;">
   <div class="column col1" style="width:180px;">
     <ul class="l2">
       <li class="item119">
         <a class="item" href="/software-testing.html"> Manual Testing </a>
      </li>
     .
     .
     .
```

Comment: Please post your HTML code snippet if possible

Comment: Updated the question with HTML code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `partial_link_text`:

```
testing = $driver.find_element(:partial_link_text, "Testing")
$driver.action.move_to(testing).perform
mt = $driver.find_element(:partial_link_text, "Manual Testing")
mt.click
```

Comment: It's not issue like - `Unable to locate element` The elements I mentioned are found but couldn't achieve selection of list element from drop-down.

Comment: Im not saying the element you are searching for is not present,but is it really what is required?....For instance consider a `red button` on top of a `square box`, requirement is to press `red button` and **not** on top surface of square box...In your case, li is like square box and achor tag is like red button.

Comment: ah, got it. I tried it but it's giving error `unable to locate element` for `mt = $driver.find_element(:partial_link_text, "Manual Testing")` I didn't understand, why this is happening eve it's correct?

Comment: Still, `unable to locate element` for `Manual Testing` link.

Comment: I normally work with java, where JavaScriptexecutor would come in handy in these kind of cases, but ruby not sure..